# Jackson ObjectMapper serializing local date into a long string

Tags: java, localdate

I am trying to serialize my myBeanObject using jackson Objectmapper.
This is what I have:

```
Objectmapper m= new Objectmapper()
m.setdateFormat(new SimpledateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
String json = m.writeValueAsString(myBeanObject);
```

Problem is a LocalDate variable in my bean is getting serialised into a long String, something like {"year":1970,"month":"JANUARY"...}

I want  the LocalDate to become simple like "1970-01-01"

Can someone please help?

Comment: what time is "myBeanObject"?

Comment: Simply remove `m.setdateFormat(new SimpledateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));`. Anyway, `LocalDate` belongs to the modern date-time API and it needs to be formatted using `DateTimeFomatter`, if required. The default format of `LocalDate#toString()` is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then setup your `ObjectMapper` as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add additional dependencies to your project, you can create a module for `ObjectMapper` yourself. Here is an example:

```
package com.yourexample.serialization
    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NoDependenciesTest {
    @Test
    public void testSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
        TestUser user = new TestUser("John Doe", LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 11));
        String json = writeToJson(user);
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"birthDate\":\"2022-12-11\"}", json);
    }

    public static String writeToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("LocalDateSerializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
        module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    private static class LocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1203520161919841191L;

        protected LocalDateSerializer() {
            super(LocalDate.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDate date, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                throws IOException {
            if (date != null) {
                generator.writeString(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TestUser {
        private String name;
        private java.time.LocalDate birthDate;

        public TestUser(String name, java.time.LocalDate birthDate) {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public java.time.LocalDate getBirthDate() {
            return birthDate;
        }

        public void setBirthDate(java.time.LocalDate birthDate) {
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }
    }
}
```